# Dual boot Linux boots into maintenance mode after Windows update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

GRUB boots my dual boot Linux/Windows desktop into Linux by default.

Today I did the Windows 10 October 2019 update.

Although Windows left GRUB unmolested, the GNOME display manager failed and Linux booted into emergency mode.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 which I updated today before updating Windows.

Comment: @PRATAP It is booting into the grub menu but from the grub menu it goes into linux maintenance mode. I have not found a remedy which mentions this--only remedies for when Windows replaces grub.

Comment: @PRATAP I tried the suggested remedy but all it did was rewrite the grub boot menu. There was nothing wrong with grub to start with, but I was willing to give it a try. Is recovery mode different from maintenance mode? I have no problem getting into my directory in command line mode, just no GUI.

Comment: @PRATAP I solved the issue. Windows update changed the block ID of the Windows partition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved the issue myself.

When Windows does the Oct 2019 update **it changes the block ID of the Windows partition!!**

So the Windows block ID in /etc/fstab must be updated!!

**SOLUTION:**

1. From linux command line type 'blkid' and note the block ID for the Windows partition
2. Edit /etc/fstab and replace the old Windows block ID with the new block ID
3. reboot